# Method with multiple @Schedule annotations does not pick second line

Tags: java, glassfish-3

I have stateless bean on Glassfish server v 3.1.2 with two methods which should be executed by schedule.
One method should be executed once in a week and annotated as follows:

```
@Schedule(dayOfWeek = "Sun", hour = "1", minute = "5", second = "0")
```

Second one runs every 15 minutes, except times when first method runs and annotated

```
@Schedules({
    @Schedule(dayOfWeek = "Mon-Sat", hour = "*", minute = "*/15", second = "0", persistent = false),
    @Schedule(dayOfWeek = "Sun", hour = "0,2-23", minute = "*/15", second = "0", persistent = false)
})
```

Problem is that second method runs every second from Saturday 23:45 until Sunday 00:00, then resumes execution nomrally, every 15 minutes. That suggests, that something wrong with Sunday schedule, but have no idea what's wrong. @Schedules Javadoc notes that this annotation available from Java 6.

Any ideas welcome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As no responses received, solution was found by experimenting. The solution was to rewrite `@Schedules` annotation as follows.

`@Schedules({
    @Schedule(dayOfWeek="Mon,Tue,Wed,Thu,Fri,Sat", hour="*", minute="*/15", second="0", persistent=false),
    @Schedule(dayOfWeek="Sun", hour="0,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23", minute="*/15", second="0", persistent=false)
    })`